# Return error when data type doesn't match submitted data (MDB2 prepare/execute)

Tags: php, error-handling, prepared-statement, mdb2

If I pass the following data to MDB2, `execute` does not return an error.  It converts the invalid text to a zero and inserts anyway.

```
$types = array('integer','integer','integer');
$data = array(
    'reviewid'      => 123, 
    'userid'        => "text$!!^^INVALID INPUT", 
    'flagid'        => 456 
);

$statement = $mdb2_dbx->prepare('
    INSERT INTO 
        review_score 
        (
            reviewid, 
            userid,
            flagid,
            dateadded
        ) VALUES (
            :reviewid,
            :userid,
            :flagid,
            NOW()
    )', $types);
$statement      = $mdb2_dbx->prepare($q, $types, MDB2_PREPARE_MANIP);
    if(PEAR::isError($statement)) { trigger_error($statement->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR); }
$affectedRows   = $statement->execute($data);
    if(PEAR::isError($affected)) { trigger_error($affectedRows->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR); }
```

Is there a way to force MDB2 to return an error if the wrong data type is encountered?

Comment: I'd rather say that your input validation is to blame. Why do you accept a non-numeric user ID in the first place? Anything after that is simply PHP and MySQL doing their magic: A string can be cast to an integer value, which is zero most of the time.

Comment: In my test example I have no input validation - purposefully trying to break it in case I overlooked something with validation.   If I understand your reply correctly, bad input will simply be cleaned/converted to the appropriate data type and inserted anyway.  Please clarify if I have this wrong.

Comment: As far as MySQL is concerned, it would convert the string into an integer in this SQL query: `INSERT INTO review_score (userid) VALUES ('string');`. I dont know the internals of MDB2, but your definition of types might already work on the PHP side and cast the userid string into an integer there. I'd say this is how it is supposed to work. Have you checked the docs of MDB2?

Comment: Yes however the documentation doesn't specifically address validation/error handling with regard to prepared statements. http://pear.php.net/manual/fr/package.database.mdb2.intro-execute.php

Comment: The only words in the docs state: "However passing an array of data types as the second parameter makes it possible to set a specific type for each placeholder." This does not imply anything. You'd actually have to look at the code to see how these types are influencing the internal handling. I tried to, but the MySQL driver code is not viewable online at pear.php.net - but you have a local copy.